# Why isn't the integrity attribute supported on anchor tags and is there a workaround?

Tags: html

I'm curious why [subresource integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) isn't supported on anchor tags, particularly for http(s) and/or `download` resources that the browser would typically handle internally (without invoking an external helper).

ie, `<a download integrity="sha..." href="http...">Some File</a>`

It seems like an extremely useful application of integrity since a compliant browser could essentially prevent or warn the user that the resource actually fetched has been modified since the page was created or in transit. If the page author cares that the user is actually downloading the same file version they originally linked to this seems like a big win (eg, a software vendor could pin the download link to a SHA hash so MITM or CDN exploits couldn't replace it with a trojan.

As a workaround, can `link` elements be hijacked to create visible links or would it need to be done entirely in JS?

Answer (score 0):

The integrity attribute is not very necessary but a *"good feature"* to use.

Firstly, the integrity attribute isn't strictly necessary. It's just a "nice to have" to prevent hackers from changing the contents of the CDN file(s).

Secondly, Use a fresh, current version of CDN(get from here):

[CDN WEBSITE](https://getbootstrap.com)